# Upgrading PHP from version 5.4.7

Tags: ubuntu, php

I'm trying to install PHP 5.4.7 by following these steps:

```
$ apt-get install libxml2-dev
$ mkdir php5-new && cd !$
$ wget -O php-5.4.7.tar.bz2 http://php.net/get/php-5.4.7.tar.bz2/from/uk3.php.net/mirror
$ bzip2 -d php-5.4.7.tar.bz2
$ tar xvf php-5.4.7.tar.gz
$ cd php-5.4.7
$ ./configure --with-mysql --with-apache2 --with-libxml --with-openssl --with-zlib --with-bz2 --with-curl --with-dom --with-gd --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-mcrypt --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-libxml --enable-ftp --enable-mbstring --enable-soap
```

But reports the error:

```
configure: error: Please reinstall the BZip2 distribution
```

However bzip2 is already installed normally.
What can it be?

Comment: Did you also install its `-dev` package?

Answer (score 0):

Run `apt-get build-dep php5` first.  This should get you all the dev libraries.